# how to check the users website login in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

i completed an ASP.NET website with Login screen. It is having levels of login like admin,user...etc.

Suppose if an employee logged in to my website from one pc and tried to login for the same employee from another pc,i need to display a message saying that same employee logged in another pc and need to logout from the first login.

Same has to be done with same pc different browser and same browser different tab login.(same as gmail or facebook login).

Please tell any method to do the same

Note:Without using Membership Concept(ASP.NET-3.5,SQL server 2008).

Comment: put a flag column in the database table of users..when user login update it as 1..and when logout make it as 0..when everytime user login first check the flag..if it is one you can show the message else just login

Comment: @Sachu  ok...but then how can i logged out from first login??

Comment: your requirement is to dont allow the user to login from multiple system or browser right? so if a user want to login from any other system or browser he need to manually logout from the first one

Comment: @Sachu : I need to  create gmail/facebook kind of login...if a user changed passord or something need to log out from all devices in which user is logged in ..not manually

Comment: at  a time user will be only logged in one system right? and u want him to logout when he changed his password? make your requirement clear

Comment: @Sachu: requirement is to dont allow the user to login from multiple system or browser. so if a user want to login from any other system or browser the site shoud logout from the all previous logins automatically...

Comment: @Rahul..ok so the requirement is not don't allow..it's to logout from other login if he tried to login from some where

Comment: I used SignalR to achieve something like this

Comment: @sachu...yes..and @ danyolgiax what is Signal R?

Comment: @Rahul hope the link can help you [avoid multiple login](http://geekswithblogs.net/Frez/articles/preventing-a-user-from-having-multiple-concurrent-sessions.aspx)

Comment: @Sachu: The link you mentioned implemented the membership concept...how can I use without membership and all....

Comment: @Sachu please helprahul, me to have the same requirement